# Filter for OS for bare metal monthly SOFTLAYER with capacity restricted

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Bare Metal Monthly service

I used following API :-
`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/271/getItemPrices.json?objectFilter={"itemPrices": {"categories": {"categoryCode": {"operation": "os"}}}}&objectMask=mask[capacityRestrictionType,pricingLocationGroup[locations],categories,item[id, description,keyName, capacity,softwareDescription[manufacturer],availabilityAttributeCount, availabilityAttributes[attributeType]]]`

datacenter -mex01

Filter OS i have applied is :
`(attribute['attributeType']['keyName'] == 'UNAVAILABLE_AFTER_DATE_NEW_ORDERS') && (expirytime >= nowTime)`

which gives me following vmware os:-

> 1)VMware Server Virtualization 6.5 Update 1g Price Id: 215293 Item Id:
>   11921,
>
> 2)VMware Server Virtualization 6.0 Price Id: 164769 Item Id: 6227,
>
> 3)VMware Server Virtualization 6.5 Price Id: 201163 Item Id: 10313

but for

1)VMware Server Virtualization 6.5 Update 1g Price Id: 215293, Item Id: 11921 gives me error:

> capacity for this price ID does not match with price id for processor
>   Quad Intel Xeon E7-4820 v2 (32 Cores, 2.00 GHz).

How do i filter VMware 6.5 update 1g through api?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue, I recommend you open a ticket in SoftLayer and attach the id, I will track the ticket.

In the meanwhile I suggest to use the following call which retrieves all OS items but no "VMware Server Virtualization 6.5 Update 1g"

`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/271/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"categories":{"categoryCode":{"operation":"os"}},"item":{"description":{"operation":"!*=1g" }}}}&objectMask=mask[capacityRestrictionType,pricingLocationGroup[locations],categories,item[id, description,keyName, capacity,softwareDescription[manufacturer],availabilityAttributeCount,availabilityAttributes[attributeType]]]`

Comment: 63509077 ticket on softlayer

Comment: After further investigation, the OS has a capacity restriction of X processors, and to see the total processors in the server you need to check the  `item.totalProcessorCapacity` value, so on this case make sure the server "Quad Intel Xeon E7-4820 v2 (32 Cores, 2.00 GHz)" meets that restriction